# Deduplication in awk using multiple arrays - works, but shouldn't. Why?

Tags: arrays, bash, csv, awk, duplicates

Input data:

```
name    date
G
A   2011-01-21
A
B   
C   2011-02-04
D
D   2011-03-26
E   2011-05-13
F   2011-02-20
G   2011-05-10
G
H
A
```

My desired output is a list of distinct values from `name` and `date` disgarding rows containing where `name`  is a duplicate and `date` is blank:

```
name    date
A   2011-01-21
B   
C   2011-02-04
D   2011-03-26
E   2011-05-13
F   2011-02-20
G   2011-05-10
H
```

My `awk` code below produces this result:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t"}
      NR==1 { print }
      NR>1 { a[$1]++ }
      NR>1 &&  $2!="" { b[$1]=$2 }
      NR>1 &&  $2=="" { c[$1]=$2 }
     END { for (i in a) {       
        if ( c[i] ) {print i,b[i]}
        else {print i,b[i]}
            }
        }
        ' test.tsv
```

However, it *shouldn't* produce the desired result because in the event `c[i]` is empty, `b[i]` should be empty and it should give up. What am I missing here please?

Comment: please update the question with what you think your `awk` script should be generating; also, are you sure you really want both the `if` and `then` to print the same results: `i,b[i]`? and if so then why bother testing anything?

Comment: does a blank `date` take precedence over a non-blank `date`? what to do if a given `name` has more than one non-blank `date` (eg, `G / 2011-05-10` and `G / 2013-11-26`)?

Comment: @markp-fuso good qn: non-blank date takes precedence. I hadn't got to the second issue you raise yet :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `c[i]` is useless, you always print the same combination. You can simplify it a bit and I think it will get clearer

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {print; next} 
             {a[$1]=a[$1]==""?$2:a[$1]} 
       END   {for(k in a) print k,a[k]}' file | column -t


name  date
A     2011-01-21
B
C     2011-02-04
D     2011-03-26
E     2011-05-13
F     2011-02-20
G     2011-05-10
H
```

only update the mapping if the value is not blank, so this will capture the first non-blank value for each key if there is any.

Assuming the values are dates you can replace the middle block with `!a[$1]{a[$1]=$2}`

Comment: Yeah, the useless `c[i]` does't help at all.  I'd taken the approach of trying to generate two arrays representing two situations (key with date value; key with blank) and then using a test to determine which one to print. Guess this was a fail! The syntax in your answer is too compressed for me to follow tbh, so I see some time with docs in my near future.

Comment: `a[$1]=a[$1]==""?$2:a[$1]` is the same as `if(a[$1]=="") a[$1]=$2`

Comment: @tesolat run a google search on `awk ternary operator` ... you should receive several hits explaining what this is (eg, [this hit](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/awk_ternary_operators.htm)) as well as plenty of examples (many from stackoverflow and/or its sister sites)